# Using an object as a data type in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to use an object and its associated attributes as part of my dataset so my model can use that object and its numerical attributes to predict another value. Is their a way to include an object as part of a dataset? The dataset also has other datatypes like ints and floats.

More specifically, I have a dataset of binary materials and their properties. I want to use a model to predict formation energy. The data includes the following:

['ID', 'Formula','formation energy','density', 'Shear Mod (Gr)', 'Shear Mod (Gvrh)', 'Shear Mod (Gv)', 'Bulk Mod (Kr)', 'Bulk Mod (Kvrh)', 'Bulk Mod (Kv)', 'Elastic Anisotropy', "Poisson's Ratio", 'crystal structure', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'alpha', 'beta', 'gamma', 'band gap', 'element 1', 'element 2']

'formation energy','density', 'Shear Mod (Gr)', 'Shear Mod (Gvrh)', 'Shear Mod (Gv)', 'Bulk Mod (Kr)',  'Bulk Mod (Kvrh)', 'Bulk Mod (Kv)', 'Elastic Anisotropy', "Poisson's Ratio", 'crystal structure', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'alpha', 'beta', 'gamma', 'band gap' are all ints or floats.

Here's an example of one material in the dataset:

```
[mp191,YRh,-0.8550205000000002,7.797625058330868,2,42.0,42.0,43.0,109.0,109.0,109.0,0.1,0.33,cubic,Pm-3m,3.443924,3.443924,3.443924,90.0,90.0,90.0,0.0,<element_objects.element.Element object at 0x000002736FCD8550>, <element_objects.element.Element object at 0x000002736FCDA630>]
```

The two Element objects at the end of the list are defined by the class and function:

```py
class Element:
    def __init__(self, formula, atomic_num, atomic_mass, melting_pt, boiling_pt, electronegativity, ea, valence,cal_rad, empirical_rad, cov_rad, vdw_rad, density):
        self.formula = formula
        self.atomic_num = atomic_num
        self.atomic_mass = atomic_mass
        self.melting_pt = melting_pt
        self.boiling_pt = boiling_pt
        self.electronegativity = electronegativity
        self.ea = ea
        self.valence = valence
        self.cal_rad = cal_rad
        self.empirical_rad = empirical_rad
        self.cov_rad = cov_rad
        self.vdw_rad = vdw_rad
        self.density = density
```

I want to use the Element's attributes as training data as well as the rest of the dataset. However, because of the Element objects, I'm unsure how to convert this dataset into a readable dataset for Tensorflow or into a Tensor. Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: What are you talking about? Can you be more precise and show an example?

Comment: Please update your question with what you have tried so far along with the specific issues/errors you are getting. Also, please make the description of your problem easier to read and understand :)